# how to edit the data present in arraylist of custom objects stored in shared preference?? i am using this class to storing and accessing

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

public class PrefConfigForProducts {
private static final String LIST_KEY_PRODUCTS = "List_Key_Products";

```
public static void writeinPref(Context context, List<List_addProducts> list_addProducts2){
    Gson gson2=new Gson();
    String jsonString2=gson2.toJson(list_addProducts2);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2=sharedPreferences2.edit();
    editor2.putString(LIST_KEY_PRODUCTS,jsonString2);
    editor2.apply();
}

public  static List<List_addProducts> readinPref(Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String jsonString2=sharedPreferences2.getString(LIST_KEY_PRODUCTS,"");
    Gson gson2=new Gson();
    Type type2=new TypeToken<ArrayList<List_addProducts>>() {}.getType();
    List<List_addProducts> list_addProducts2=gson2.fromJson(jsonString2,type2);
    if(list_addProducts2==null){
        list_addProducts2=new ArrayList<>();
    }


    
    return list_addProducts2;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st) get the list from pref and store it in an array.
2) add new data in that array.
3) Save that entire list in the pref again

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

**1)** create new method with one parameter **index** then Read the SharedPreferences data to your List<List_addProducts> object.

**2)** then access the Object from that List<List_addProducts> using index and modify it

**3)** update that object in List<List_addProducts> using set method

**4)** Save List<List_addProducts> back to the SharedPreferences